# what time should I choose for the last event and "take care of"?

Tags: phrase-usage, tense

I read a comic book. I will say a little preface. The villain immobilized his comrades. And the main character says, "*that takes care of they (the enforcers in the comic book)*". Isn't it necessary to use the future or continuous here? What is the reason for choosing Present Simple?  I can not understand.

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask them separately. I have removed the second question from your post and you can ask that in a new post.

Comment: Surely it would be "That takes care of _them_"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idiom: to take care of something, to handle it, to do what needs to be done.

Basically, when finishing up a task,  you would or might say it: That takes care of that.

Here, he immobilizes them and says it. **It is an idiomatic usage**.

He could have been cooking dinner, washing his clothes in a washing machine or taking out the trash or programming a rocket to the moon. As one finishes a task, one often say: That [the action[ takes care of [the task]. And it usually means the task was not pleasant or was difficult or a pain in the tail.